# Using Java to run Applet on localhost is blocked

Tags: java, localhost, jnlp

I am using a local web server on my computer to test a jar file that I am going to use the Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP) to use that is going to be included in my website, but I am having a problem with Java not allowing the JNLP file to be run.

[image: Application Blocked by Java Security]

I tried to remedy the problem by adding `localhost` to my exception list in the Java Control Panel but the block message keeps coming up. How can I stop this?

[image: Java Control Panel]

Comment: *"How can I stop this?"* Click the link with 'more information'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson You can safely assume that I looked at that link before posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)
From what I read on the [description of the exception site list](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml) it could be that you need to self sign your application. (But I would try the other suggestions first)

(2) What you also must [ensure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/exception_site_list.html):

> "For Java Web Start applications, the URL for the main JNLP file must
>   be in the list. If the URL for the main JNLP file cannot be
>   determined, then the exceptions do not apply to the RIA."

(3) Other than that I would play around with it a bit:

- did you try adding some more entries to the list like `http://127.0.0.0` or the actual IP?
- do you use a specific port? If so you need to add it...
- Did you chose the right protocol http vs https vs file?

Comment: The trick for me was adding the specific port number which is easy to overlook. `http://localhost:6405/` This helped with SAP Business Objects.